# CORS Preflight 403, but I have proper header

Tags: php, angular, cors

Working on an ionic app that calls an api on a webserver for database interaction. I've done this once before and copied the code from that project, but it isn't working.

Here are the headers I have on the php webserver:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

And this is the error I get when I try and fire off a POST from the app:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <url remove by me> with MIME type text/html.
Failed to load <url removed by me>: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The status code is 403 Forbidden

It took some fiddling around to get the headers to work for the previous project, and these are the same set of headers. It is hosted on a different server this time, but I'm not sure if that makes any difference for CORS. The file exists and that is the correct path to it. If I navigate directly to the api page, the headers show Access-Control-Allow-Origin *... but trying to get it from the app just isn't working.

Any help is appreciated. CORS can be such a pain.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework? For example Laravel?

Comment: @fransyozef I am not. Just straight pure php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions yesterday, I finally figured out what it was. After nothing seemed to make any difference or change in the response I contacted the hosting company. Turns out they block OPTIONS requests on the lowest hosting tier.

So if anyone else runs into this, contact your hosting company and see if it is on their end.

Answer (score 2):

A preflight request cannot include cookies or other common authentication headers and must receive a `200 OK` response.

Your server is responding with `403 Forbidden`. You need to exclude OPTIONS requests from the requirement to be authorised.

> If I navigate directly to the api page

… then you are making a GET request, not a preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: Yeah, I looked up the requirements for the preflight. Initially I was getting a location issue and fixed that (missing www in url). I'm not doing any authorization on the API at the moment. Is this one of the headers I'm passing in or do I need to do some sort of test for request method and have that basically just return nothing for "OPTIONS"?

Navigating directly to page, yeah... was just testing if the header was even there with that.

Comment: "I'm not doing any authorization on the API at the moment." — *Something* is causing the server to respond with a 403 Forbidden response. If you don't have any authn/authz on it, then you'll need to find out what that is.

Comment: "do I need to do some sort of test for request method and have that basically just return nothing for "OPTIONS"" — Nothing except the CORS permission headers.